# How to check if the X or Y component of a Vector3 has increased or decreased

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, 2d

I have a Vector3 that contains information about a gameOjects position in worldspace, I’m wondering if it’s possible to query the x and y component to see if it’s changed?

Cheers in advance for your help

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing in the Vector3 class that allows you to record or observe value changes. Assuming that "see if its changed" means "see if its changed since the last call of my member method", you could possibly store a copy of the position in a member variable and compare it against the current position in its next invoke of your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query an object's position at any time using `gameObject.transform.position`, which will give you the position in world space. If you save that position to a variable, you can check if and how it changed in the next frame:

```
Vector3 oldPosition; // the Vector you want to compare to
Vector3 delta = transform.position - oldPosition; 
// delta now contains how much the position has changed since oldPosition
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I’ll try that when I’m home and let you know if it works out